# File selection with keyboard in file manager

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files

elementary's file manager is selecting files like a rectangle. I have switched from windows to elementary OS. In Windows, with presing <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>-></kbd> (Right) you can select line by line  starting from the left when upper line is selected.

Like :

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6
7,8,9,10,11,12
```

But elementary OS selecting is like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 x x x x x
3 x x x x x
4 x x x x x
5 x x x x x
6 x x x x x
```

How can I select files like in Windows?

Comment: Try another file manager like Nautilus or Nemo

Comment: This issue has been fixed in the next version (to be released in Loki). See https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1399674

Answer (score 1):

You can hold control to select multiple files. (I believe this works in Windows as wel)
You can also use shift to select consecutive files, though you have to click the little tick at the top of the files.